# How to clear textbox on HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

I have code in html like this

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src='LatihanKuisJs.js'></script>
    <body>
        <form name="kuis">
            <table border="1" width="50%">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" >Celcius
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="80%">Kelvin</td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="kelvin">
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="80%">Reamur</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" id="reamur"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="80%">Fahrenheit</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" id="fahrenheit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick='calculateCelcius();'/>
            <br/><br/>
            <textarea rows="20" cols="90" id="textarea">
            </textarea>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick='clear();'/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and external javascript function like this:

```
function calculateCelcius(){
    var kelvin = document.getElementById('kelvin');
    var reamur = document.getElementById('reamur');
    var fahrenheit = document.getElementById('fahrenheit');
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

    var hasil=(kelvin.value*1 + reamur.value*1 + fahrenheit.value*1);
    textarea.value += hasil + '\n';
}

function clear(){
    document.getElementById("textarea").value="";
}
```

When I tried to click the clear button on my page, the text area wasn't clear. 
What's wrong? And what should I do?

Comment: Return some error into the console of your browser?

Comment: First thing would be to check your browser's developer tools console (hit F12 to open the developer tools, if you're using Firefox then you'll want to install Firebug first) and see if there are any errors being reported.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just rename your function from `clear` to something like `clearTextarea` and it will work.

The `clear()` method refers to obsolete `document.clear()` method, which is described at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.clear) as:

> This method used to clear the whole specified document in early
>   (pre-1.0) versions of Mozilla. In recent versions of Mozilla-based
>   applications as well as in Internet Explorer and Netscape 4 this
>   method does nothing.

Also according to [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-clear):

> The `clear()` method must do nothing.

**References:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.clear
2. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-clear

Comment: +1 - Hm, this is correct. Is clear a reserved word there? I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/292Ra/ which shows it working as cleart

Comment: @TravisJ I'm just trying to find any evidence of that.

Comment: Changing the onclick to `onclick="console.log(clear)"` shows that `clear` is a native method in the context of the textarea handler (Chrome 26).  No idea why.

Comment: The tutorialspoint reference is documentation for the Prototype JavaScript library.  This isn't part of the standard DOM.

Comment: @searlea Yes, this is deprecated `document.clear()` method, which is yet supported by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

if you use a function like this one

```
function clearInput(element){
element.value="";
}
```

then in the input add this

```
onfocus="clearInput(this)"
```

this can be used multiple times for any text fields or text areas because the id of the object is passed where it calls the function from.

RKillah

Answer (score -2):

Try adding javascript: before your function name when defining onclick event.
Something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick='javascript: clear();'/>
```

Comment: This isn't right.  The `javascript:` prefix is only ever needed in `href` or `src` attributes, never in event handlers.